# Django not streaming properly when running in a virtual machine

Tags: python, django

I have an application which is using django as backend and react as UI.
In the backend, it simply subscribe a remote publisher, and sending data to UI.

If I run the application in host machine (mac OS), it works perfect. From the browser console, I can see the UI is receiving data and logged in the console. The total data size is larger than 2 MB.

When I run it in a virtual machine (CentOS 7), and open it through host's browser, I can see the data is streaming, but with much smaller size, around 10 KB, and it never logged in the browser console.

Initially I thought it may be caused by the connection, so I tested the connection speed between the host and the client. The speed test result is 3Gb/s so looks like the connection is fine.

Then I also tried give more processor and memory to the virtual machine, but still the same. (I gave 6 processors and 12G memory)

I tried search on the internet but couldn't find any solutions.

Here are some code example:

## django

```
def stream_data(request):
    context = zmq.Context()
    sock = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    sock.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
    ip_addr = get_public_ip()
    port = '5570'
    sock.connect('tcp://{0}:{1}'.format(ip_addr, port))

    resp = StreamingHttpResponse(stream_generator(sock), content_type="text/event-stream")
    resp['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
    resp['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'no'
    return resp

def stream_generator(sock):
    while True:
        message = sock.recv()
        yield 'data:{0}\n\n'.format(encode_base64(raw))
```

## UI

```
source = new EventSource(addr);

source.onopen = function open() {
   console.log('Connection established.');
};

source.onmessage = (e) => {
  console.log(e.data)
}
```

I'm expecting both should behave the same, but running on virtual machine not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you need to check the 'SETTINGS' file in django.  Look that you have added the ip address of the virtual machine to the "ALLOWED_HOSTS" list.

Comment: In the settings.py, I have added "ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']", and I can open the ui and see the streaming connection was connected.